# Turn off Lynx Commands in Email

Tags: cron, ubuntu-10.04

How do I turn off receiving an email from lynx that recaps what it did?

I have crontab running a PHP script and that works fine. But each time cron runs my lynx browser I get an email from the cron daemon recapping the lynx commands.

I don't need them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found it....

append `>/dev/null 2>&1` to the end of your cron command line

Answer (score 1):

It isn't `lynx` that is sending e-mail — it's `cron`. This is a feature: by default, any output of cron jobs gets mailed to the owner of the crontab. You can find the documentation for this in `man 5 crontab`, but in short, if you want to suppress all mailed output, set `MAILTO=""` at the top of your crontab file. Alternately, you can suppress output from the individual jobs (in a per-command-specific way, like `grep --quiet` if you happen to have grep commands in your crontab), or redirect the output elsewhere — to a log file, or just to `/dev/null`. Or, you can pipe it to the `mail` command, using `-s` to give the mail a meaningful subject rather than the default (ugly) cron-output subject line.